# Extract robot position from rosbag

Tags: transforms, rosbag, tf2, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I recorded tf-messages (while driving the robot) into a bagfile and wrote a ros node that should extract the positions (base_link-frame) from that bag file.

My idea was to use a tf::Transformer and feed it with all the transforms stored in the tf-messages:

```
rosbag::Bag bag;
bag.open("tf.bag", rosbag::bagmode::Read);
std::vector<std::string> topics;
topics.push_back("/tf");

rosbag::View view(bag, rosbag::TopicQuery(topics));

tf::Transformer transformer;

BOOST_FOREACH(rosbag::MessageInstance const m, view)
{
    //instantiate bag message
    tf::tfMessage::ConstPtr tfPtr = m.instantiate<tf::tfMessage>();

    BOOST_FOREACH(geometry_msgs::TransformStamped const tfs, tfPtr->transforms)
    {
        tf::StampedTransform stampedTf;
        tf::transformStampedMsgToTF(tfs, stampedTf);
        //setTransform returns true!
        transformer.setTransform(stampedTf);
        ...
    }
}
```

The method setTransform(...) always returns true, so I thought that it works...
Each time I get a transform with child_frame == /robot_1/base_link I want to get the map-base_link-transform at the time of this last transform. But the transformer returns false:

```
if(transformer.canTransform(baseLink, mapFrame, stampedTf.stamp_)==true){
    //lookup transform
    transformer.lookupTransform(baseLink, mapFrame, stampedTf.stamp_, temp);
}
```

A few additional facts:
The transformer's latest common time is always = 0:

```
transformer.getLatestCommonTime(baseLink, mapFrame, time, NULL)
```

And printing all tf-messages of the bag shows that the tf-tree should be consistent (I'm using stage and used view_frames):

```
/map -> /robot_1/odom -> /robot_1/base_footprint -> /robot_1/base_link -> /robot_1/base_laser_link
```

Is something wrong with my code or idea?
Any suggestions for a better solution?

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/63193/extract-robot-position-from-rosbag/) by [simonw](https://answers.ros.org/users/4946/simonw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2013-05-21

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [carlosjoserg](https://answers.ros.org/users/4768/carlosjoserg/) on 2015-05-05**:
Hi there, many thanks, I was looking exactly this! It worked for me! But changed: 'std::vectorstd::string topics;' -> 'std::string topic("tf");', 'rosbag::View view(bag, rosbag::TopicQuery(topics));' -> rosbag::View view(bag, rosbag::TopicQuery(topic));', and deleted 'topics.push_back("/tf");'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I know it would not really answer your question about whether your approach is correct. I am not familiar with rosbag API.

What I know should work is playing back the bag file and having a node with tf::TransformListener do the work of calculating your pose. Your node could look similar to [this](https://github.com/uml-robotics/robot_tools/blob/master/src/pose_publisher.cpp).

---

Originally posted by [mmedvede](https://answers.ros.org/users/1773/mmedvede/) with karma: 221 on 2013-05-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sorry for necroposting, but this might be interesting for who lands here and reads this:

I also encountered a problem and released a python package called [tf_bag](https://github.com/marcoesposito1988/tf_bag) to use recorded tf data in a script. Hope this can be helpful.

---

Originally posted by [marcoesposito1988](https://answers.ros.org/users/7591/marcoesposito1988/) with karma: 191 on 2017-09-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1